# Eclipse / Tomcat Java EE Workingdir

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, working-directory

when i develop an Webapplication in eclipse the runtime workingdir is the Basepath of my Project

```
c:\workspace\project <-- Workingdir
c:\workspace\project\WebContent
```

but when i deploy it to an live unix tomcat "WebContent" is my working dir.

Now i have an config file

```
WebContent\WEB-INF\repository.xml
```

and a Spring bean which points to this file

```
<bean id="config" class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfig" factory-method="create">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="WebContent/WEB-INF/repository.xml" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="JACKRABBITREPOSITORY" />
</bean>
```

this will not work on the unix tomcat, because he would look for a subdir "WebContent", but he is already in this dir.

How can i make

```
c:\workspace\project\WebContent
```

the working dir in eclipse, so both can use the same path

Answer (score 0):

put it in `../WEB-INF/classes/` dir and reference it directly as this this path is always going to be in your classpath.

```
<bean id="config" class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfig" factory-method="create">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="repository.xml" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="JACKRABBITREPOSITORY" />
</bean>
```

you can even create a dir for this like "config" like `../WEB-INF/classes/config/repository.xml`

```
<bean id="config" class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfig" factory-method="create">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="classpath:config/repository.xml" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="JACKRABBITREPOSITORY" />
</bean>
```